# In Power BI report Builder i want pull the info in same row which has a another data set relation how i need to proceed

Tags: powerbi

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ProductionPlanOrRecordMenuItemId.Value, 
Fields!ProductionPlanOrRecordMenuItemId.Value, 
Fields!PlanCount.Value,
"PlanOrRecordMenuItemServingGroups"), ", ")
```

but it was returning the value which also in Source table Fields!PlanCount.Value what can i do can any one help me out on this issue

Thanks in Advance

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ProductionPlanOrRecordMenuItemId.Value, 
Fields!ProductionPlanOrRecordMenuItemId.Value, 
Fields!PlanCount.Value,
"PlanOrRecordMenuItemServingGroups"), ", ")
```

used this and got the source table data in out 100

but i was execting the 10,20,30